# How to disable login sound?

Tags: login, gdm, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the drum beat sound on the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24946/how-do-i-disable-the-drum-beat-sound-on-the-login-screen)

How do I disable the login sound?

I have tried all guides on the internet I can find, but they are for previous versions and I can't find an option anywhere.