# How do I disable startup sound in 11.10?

Tags: sound, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable login sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound)

There is no option to disable this sound (the one after you log in, when entering gnome), and it is not present anymore in the program startup list like it was in 11.04...

Comment: this was answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound/66789#66789)

Answer (score -2):

[How to Disable Login Sound on Ubuntu](http://maketecheasier.com/disable-login-sound-in-ubuntu-oneiric-quick-tips/2011/09/15)

Comment: If you found an answer and know it to be true why not use that information and post a nice complete answer here for everyone to see? That site can be down tomorrow and the information not there anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please do not use shortlinks.