# No login sound on startup

Tags: 11.10, sound, login

When I start my Ubuntu 11.10, no login sound is heard. All the settings are the normal and I can hear the audio but no log in sound on startup. What to do?

Answer (score 4):

There are some reasons :

- The sound may be muted or has been set to zero value.

  For this, check the right most corner and click on the **sound icon** and raise your sound volume.
- The login sound could be disabled from the  **Startup applications**. It can be found in right most corner of your screen from where you logout.

  For this, verify that a check sign is there on **Gnome login sound**.
- Or if you changed something accidentally and don't know what you changed.

  Then use this method:

  Install [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] from software-center and then open it.

  Go to `org/ gnome/desktop/application/sound` and then point your cursor to *event-sounds*. On the bottom of dconf editor, there is to **set to default** option, click on it and log out and login from your account.

Answer (score 0):

Click the power button at the top-right of the screen and select *Startup Applications*. Scroll down the list and make sure that *GNOME Login Sound* is enabled.

That's the method I use to disable the login sound anyway.

Comment: This setting is hidden by default in 11.10, see here for how to access it again: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound. Also, @arun most people are happy to have it disabled, sorry I can't help you turn it back on...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried at the login screen, on the top right corner:  is the sound icon on mute? It happened to me that it was on mute and I couldn't hear the welcome sound (or login sound)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this. Run this command on terminal:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/* /usr/share/sounds/
```