# turn off sound on login page in 12.04

Tags: sound, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable login sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound)

how do i turn off the startup sound on the login page in precise?

it used to work with

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/sound/event_sounds --type bool false
```

thanks