# How do I disable the startup sound in Ubuntu 12.04 login-screen?

Tags: sound, 12.04, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable login sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound)

I would like to know how to disable the *startup sound* in Ubuntu 12.04 login-screen; that is, the sound produced at the login-screen **before the login**.

Please note, however, the *login sound* is the sound produced by the system **after the login**. The following question covers the procedure on how to disable the *login sound* in Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier versions: [How to disable login sound?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66786/how-to-disable-login-sound)