# Disabling drum beat login sound on Precise 12.04 with gnome-shell

Tags: 12.04, gdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the startup sound in Ubuntu 12.04 login-screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123759/how-do-i-disable-the-startup-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-login-screen)

Yes I know this is an old chestnut, but I can't find a solution for my case. I want to disable the drum-beat logon screen sound, but I **can't use the standard recipe** of `system > preferences > startup applications > logon sound` because I'm using gnome-shell and there isn't a system preferences menu.

So: if I did make the [change as specified for Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24946/how-do-i-disable-the-drum-beat-sound-on-the-login-screen), what config file(s) would be changed on disk? If I know that, I can make the change myself. The trouble with answers that just say "pull up this menu and untick this box" is that I can't tell what's actually going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom, using Ubuntu Tweak from the answers to that question has solved it for me. I don't think it's an exact duplicate, so if you add that as answer I can accept it. Or we can close this question as a duplication - I don't particularly mind.

Comment: I'll close it as a dupe - that ubuntu-tweak answer looks a bit thin - if you have some time, do you mind editing that answer to reflect the steps you had to do to do disable the drum sound?