# Why don't I have ubuntu tweak setting to mute/enable ubuntu login sound?

Tags: 12.04, sound, lightdm, login-screen

Ever since I installed Ubuntu 12.04, I couldn't figure out a way to enable the login sound.

I already have ubuntu tweak installed and I have been at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123759/how-do-i-disable-the-startup-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-login-screen), but on my ubuntu, there is not any setting to mute/enable login sound at "Login Settings" tab, only to change the theme.

Also I've tried the following:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-startup-login-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise.html
and
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/enable-gnome-login-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

None of them worked. Anyone has any idea on why I can't change login sound settings?
I'm sure the sound is not muted at login screen.

Comment: I have **Ubuntu Tweak 0.7.1**, on **Ubuntu 12.04**, and it has an option (under login settings) to enable/disable login sounds.  What version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 0.6.2 also on Ubuntu 12.04.
I'll try updating and see if it works.

Comment: Well I have updated it to version 0.7.2 and now in fact there is an option to enable login sound. However, by default it is set to ON but still there is no startup ubuntu sound, just a little beep when  login screen comes up, no sound after login at all... the classical drum beat that was on previous versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Agreed. Same behavior I get.

Comment: Hum, so that means they removed the login sound? I thought they had just disabled it. Well, is not extremely necessary but I miss it sometimes lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to a more recent version of Ubuntu Tweak (0.7.2) allows to you change settings for login sound.