# Strange audio sound of thunder starts over after my laptop starts in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

Strange audio sound of thunder starts over after my laptop starts.Unable to know what is playing this sound. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

By default the display manager LightDM is called for a graphical login interface. A drum beat sound will indicate that it is ready for input of user credentials to log in.

To disable this see:

- [How do I disable the drum beat sound on the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24946/how-do-i-disable-the-drum-beat-sound-on-the-login-screen)