# Loud and annoying noise on login

Tags: sound

I have a PC with Kubuntu 13.10 64-bit on it. The problem is that whenever I log in (automatic log in is enabled), there is a loud double-click noise that sounds from the speakers whether the volume is muted or not. I have two sound cards; the motherboard audio, which is disabled in the BIOS, and the Creative! Labs Sound Blaster X-Fi SB0460, which I have normal speakers plugged into. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Relative `lspci` lines:

```
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
02:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs SB X-Fi
```

Using default Phonon backend.

*(I am not really sure what other information to provide, but will gladly edit in anything upon request.)*

Comment: Try if this helps (Kubuntu should also use lightdm): http://askubuntu.com/questions/24946/how-do-i-disable-the-drum-beat-sound-on-the-login-screen

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; unfortunately, it did not work. It's not the default Ubuntu login sound: it doesn't sound like a double drum beat, but more like two rapid, harsh clicking noises.