# Where is Ubuntu's drum roll sound located?

Tags: sound, login, unity-greeter

Where is Ubuntu's logon sound (Triple Drum Roll) located? It plays right when you see the Unity Greeter? When I searched up for the startup/login sound, which is what I thought it was, I got results referring to "desktop-login.ogg", which sounds like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQaEXZ-df6Y). Any help here?

Comment: /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/24946/how-do-i-disable-the-drum-beat-sound-on-the-login-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since at least version 13.10, it's been here: /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg

Answer (score 1):

The drum sound presented with the login dialogue is in

> /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg

The drum sound played upon successful login is in

> /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg