# Play audio of video file on login

Tags: gnome, login, mp4

I want to play an mp4 file when my account is logged into. How can I do this?

It should be noted that the file also has video, so I only want the sound to be played, and not the video to be shown. And I also don't want any program to be visually launched, so for instance if on every startup VLC Player launched playing that file that would not be acceptable.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Care to have the video converted to Ogg Vorbis? You do say "audio file" in the title, and then say "file also has video"... which is just plain ridiculous.

Comment: @muru: "Ogg Vorbis"?

Comment: Ogg is a container format, Vorbis is a free audio codec. It is the most popular free audio format, except perhaps FLAC. The Ubuntu login sounds, for example, are/were always in `.ogg`.

Comment: Simply converting the file to an audio file would make the question much simpler, and people much more willing  to help you

Answer (score 1):

You have a two-fold question, both have been answered before:

[Convert video to audio](https://askubuntu.com/q/80954/295286)

and

[Replace the system ready sound](https://askubuntu.com/a/66788/295286)

**TL;DR**: convert video to audio first, then replace the audio file that plays with the one you want. Remember to keep original file as backup

Comment: Well, firstly Ubuntu GNOME does not have a noise on login, and secondly, in the `/usr/share/sounds/` there is no `ubuntu` folder, nor do any of the others lead to anything other than the default alert sounds seemingly.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda you're using Ubuntu GNOME. Only Ubuntu has the classic login sound, via [`ubuntu-sounds`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/all/ubuntu-sounds/filelist). Same difference.

Comment: @muru: So do I need to install that package then?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Nah. You should just run `canberra-gtk-play /path/to/some/file.ogg` [at startup](http://askubuntu.com/a/48327/158442).