# How to disable drum beat sound when closing FF in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, unity, sound, firefox

Please note, this is the same drum beat sound from login, the difference is this sound occurs whenever I try to close Firefox or Palemoon, and it's not browser related, because Opera does not play this sound when closing. I've posted this question in Mozilla's forum  and someone told me that he has the same problem when receiving system notification, so it seems an Ubuntu configuration and not FF. Anyone had similar problem and succeeded to disable it?
My environment: Ubuntu 16.04, Unity Tweak Tool (don't know if it has anything to do with the problem), FF 60.8.0esr.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the drum beat sound on the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24946/how-do-i-disable-the-drum-beat-sound-on-the-login-screen)

Comment: Do you want to delete the drum roll from everywhere or just from the FF minimise?

Comment: Actually on minimize, it's OK, there's no drum roll, but on closing the sound comes up. I'd like to remove it from only FF, if it's too complicate, then remove it from everywhere.

Comment: That's actually a warning sound. You might have enabled, *"Warn you when closing multiple tabs"*. You can either disable that or follow the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: @Kulfy, thanks for your reply, I never noticed that there are two warnings: a pop up screen and sound, I'll follow the steps above to disable it.

Comment: @Kulfy, sorry, didn´t work, the above solution is only for login sound, indeed, the login sound is gone, but the FF one continues, any other idea?